# Install swiper slider on Laravel project

Tags: javascript, npm, swiper.js, laravel-9

how can I install the swiper slider package on my Laravel 9 project?

Package link : [swiperjs.com](https://swiperjs.com/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Laravel 9 with Vite and Tailwind. Follow these steps to use Swiper with all its modules:

1. **Install Swiper**

   `npm install swiper`
2. **Add Swiper styles to your *app.css***

   `@import 'swiper/css/bundle';`

   Note: If you are using Tailwind you should import Swiper *before* the Tailwind assets.
3. **Add Swiper to your *app.js***

   `import Swiper from 'swiper/bundle';`

Answer (score 3):

The correct version of integration into Laravel 8/9 using webpack that does not contradict the swiper documentation may look like this:

Install swiperjs :

```
npm install swiper
```

Then inside the file resources/sass/app.scss :

```
@import 'node_modules/swiper/swiper';
```

if you need navigation/pagination or another modules add lines:

```
@import 'node_modules/swiper/modules/navigation/navigation';
@import 'node_modules/swiper/modules/pagination/pagination';
```

And inside the file /resources/js/app.js :

```
import { Autoplay, Navigation, Pagination } from "swiper";
import Swiper from "swiper";
Swiper.use([Autoplay, Navigation, Pagination]);
```

(in the example above, I added Autoplay property).
And after then where to add the code (for example in blades):

```
<div class="swiper mySwiperClass">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        ...
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <!-- If we need controls 
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    -->
</div>

<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        const swiper = new Swiper('.mySwiperClass', {
            spaceBetween: 15,
            slidesPerView: 3, 
            pagination: {
              el: ".swiper-pagination",
              clickable: true
            },
            speed: 1000,
            loop: true,
            autoplay: {
              delay: 2500,
              disableOnInteraction: false,
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If you are using Vite, you will need to add `window.Swiper = Swiper` after importing `Swiper`.

Answer (score 2):

Well I guess this is the only answer on the internet that properly installs `swiperjs` in laravel (v9.x) and works.

**Caution :** According to the comment and provided link by @ktscript, the following approach is a bad practice which is recommended **not** to use by swiper official website.

*But still I won't delete my answer in case you don't have any other options on the table.*

**If you've found it useless just let me know in the comments so I'll delete my answer.**

Install swiperjs :

`npm install swiper`

Then inside the file `resources/sass/app.scss` :

`@import 'node_modules/swiper/swiper';`

**Notice:** You can't import the styles with a `~` at the beginning.

And inside the file `/resources/js/app.js` :

`const Swiper = require('swiper').default;`

The `.default` is necessary after `require()`.

**UPDATE :** Now I found out that I can import swiper like below.

```
import {Swiper, Navigation, Pagination} from 'swiper';
```

Tested with `Laravel v9.x` and `swiperjs v8.x`.

Comment: This is bad practice, Hooman, and the official swiper site strongly recommends using the esm (https://swiperjs.com/migration-guide) approach rather than require.

Comment: Thanks @ktscript, I've updated my answer with a Caution paragraph, so people know there's a right and better way to install ```swiper.js```.

Comment: No, thank you, @Hooman! Although your answer is not entirely correct, but it helped to sort out the problem.